# Determine geographic center (in latitude, longitude) of US Census tracts

Tags: geocoding

Does any API exist to return latitude/longitude of US census tracts? Specifically, I'm looking to return the geographical center of each census tract. How would I best go about doing this?

Comment: Do you plan on storing this data locally, or do you need it as an intermediate data point?

Comment: Please specify the GIS software and/or framework you intend to use. An API to process data makes no sense without data.